# Can't remove CodeDeploy agent on centos 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I use the command :

```
sudo yum erase codedeploy-agent
```

to uninstall the codedeploy-agent. But can not uninstall and log error as follows:

```
Stop codedeploy-agent in preun hook if this is an erase.
Stopping codedeploy-agent:Unable to stop the running codedeploy-agent
Canceling uninstall of the agent..
error: %preun(codedeploy-agent-1.2.1-1868.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package codedeploy-agent-1.2.1-1868.noarch
  Verifying  : codedeploy-agent-1.2.1-1868.noarch                                                                                                                                                                                     
1/1

Failed:
  codedeploy-agent.noarch 0:1.2.1-1868

Complete!
```

When I changed the user profile to run the codedeploy-agent but I set the wrong username so the error was generated.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codedeploy-agent-non-root-profile/

The status of the codedeploy-agent

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
sudo: unknown user: ec2-user
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```